# Can anyone create chat room

Tags: support

I am new to stackexchange community (not exactly new, but know very less about it), so I just wanted to know if anyone can create a chat room? If yes, then how?

Comment: No... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: Sometime a question is better answered during chat than a formal Q&A. How to ask then?

Comment: @Kav Get 100 reputation by participating on main site. Basically, chat doesn’t come for free; it was never meant to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> know if anyone can create a chat room

Not everybody can. In order to create a chat room, you need to have 100 reputation. Please see: [What is reputation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [Privileges](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

> If yes, then how?

If you *can* create one, it is as simple as going to chat (click on the Stack Exchange logo at the top-right, then chat), scrolling to the bottom of the page, and clicking the orange "create a new room" button.